# Set the column value to a fixed length

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, with a column called 'postalcode', with 4 digitals(like 1234) only.

However, when I scraped from website, the postalcode column sometimes get more than 4 digitals, like 123456789.

What is the best way to set the value length of the column to only choose the first 4 digitals for the 'postalcode' column?

```
City Postalcode
A    1234
B    234567890
C    5678
...  ....
```

Desired results:

```
 City Postalcode
 A    1234
 B    2345
 C    5678
 ...  ...
```

Comment: Is it always the first 4 values you need?

Comment: Yes, always 4 digitals for postalcode

Comment: @ElizabethShen it is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is called `df` and the column is of type `String` then you can just slice the values:

```py
df['Postalcode'] = df['Postalcode'].str[:4]
```

You can also use [str.slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"ali":[111111,4132123,342131,543545,76767]})
data["truncated"] = data.ali.apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[:4]))
data.head()

#output

    ali truncated
0   111111  1111
1   4132123 4132
2   342131  3421
3   543545  5435
4   76767   7676
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It seems that we are in the same city :-)

Comment: @ElizabethShen accept the answer to remove it from active questions

Comment: I already accepted the first answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first answer worked very well. I do not know why now deleted.
The answer is simple but useful:
df['Postalcode']=df['Postalcode'].str[:4]

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe i did some wrong operation? I was trying to click to accept it the first time, but not work. Then i tried to click the up triangle, it already -1. The answer is there again, so I clicked Accept again, it worked! When I clicked the up triangle, it returns to 0, If I click again, it become -1 again :-)))((((

Comment: Yeah someone else downvoted me, not you. But thank you though, glad it helped you!